# Should we be editing answers that have incorrect instructions now that the users' profiles interface has been redesigned?

Tags: discussion, edits, profile-page, meta, per-site-meta

For example I ran into [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/251157/revisions) about how to access your flair. It had outdated information since the flair page link is not where it used to be now. So I edited it with a new screen shot and written navigation instructions on how to reach the flair page.

I think I should be editing these when I run into them. However, it scares me a little if this design is not ***"final" "finalized"*** yet, and some more things move to other places, then my edits will become incorrect and we'll have to re-edit again.

So should we already be editing these types of deprecated navigation answers or should we wait a while before spending any time on this?

Comment: We should wait until the next update to make sure these new updates have time to be considered stable enough

Comment: I think that is a fine edit. Maybe don't edit things that may change / seem buggy / have been reported as bugs.